# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, When using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, telegram-bot

Why am I getting this error When I use `async`?

**My Code:**

```
bot.onText(/\/start/, async  msg => {
  const opts = {
    parse_mode: 'Markdown' ,
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: StartKeyboard,
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true
    })
  };
  await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Hi', opts);
});
```

**Error:**

```
bot.onText(/\/start/, async  msg => {
                      ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I'm using node.js v6.11.0 with "dependencies":

```
{ "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
  "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
  "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
  "firebase": "^4.1.2",
  "firebase-admin": "^5.0.0",
  "node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.27.1",
  "request": "^2.81.0" },
```

Comment: Does your environment support async/await syntax?

Comment: I'm using node.js v6.11.0 with "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "firebase": "^4.1.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.0.0",
    "node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.27.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0"
  },

Comment: 6.11.0, That is okey in my playground, but when I want to run with `node index.js` I get This Error, maybe that is for es6 or ...

Comment: async/await is ES2017.  IIRC Node didn't get async/await until version 7.10.

Comment: @Amy But with the polyfill that should be solved anyways, right?

Comment: in my playground every things is okey with `import 'babel-polyfill';` but in `node index.js` I have import error and i Changed that to  This `require('babel-polyfill');` but I got async error

Comment: `babel-polyfill` do not fix syntax errors, just "API" related things (Map, Set, Array...). You need to call `babel` to transform you code to a runnable version. I usually use `babel-node` to do so.

Comment: That would work if you run the code through babel first to generate ES6, before running it with Node.

Comment: @Amy I think it's async/await is enabled by default from **Node v7.6**. Sedric Could you bump up your node version to > 8.x? If you can [tj/n](https://github.com/tj/n) - node's version manager will make it super easy.

Comment: In windows 64 latest version is 6.11.3 in official website

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei no, that's the latest LTS release. the current release is 8.5.

Comment: Ah tj/n wont work on windows then. But you should be able to download the v8 from the site if you chose **Current** [Link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)

Comment: Oh Thank you, I will install that now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your version of NodeJS (6.11 LTS) is too old and does not support the `async/await` features. The syntax error is a result of the Javascript interpreter not recognizing the `async` token and getting confused about arguments.

Upgrade to NodeJS 7.6 or later. https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await

In prior versions, the only way to perform asynchronous behaviour is to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Is there any way to use async in node.js 6? Because I want to run in android server with `dory node` application

Comment: There are other ways to do asynchronous work, such as promises or streams. However, the `async` and `await` keywords cannot be used in older versions.

Comment: Still getting this error on: Node.js v14.15.0.

Comment: @Kristian are you sure this is happening in an async/await situation or do you just have a syntax error?

Comment: @Kristian I've added an answer which may be helpful to people seeing this on newer versions of Node.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to/can't update your node version, try using babel presets.
I had the same error using ES6 with jest (node v6.9.1).

Just add these two modules to your dependencies

```
npm install --save babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-0
```

And add a file `.babelrc` to your root dir with the following code:

```
{ "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"] }
```

And if you are not using it already, install `babel-cli` and run your application with `babel-node` command

```
sudo npm install -g babel-cli

babel-node app.js
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're seeing this error with a newer version of Node, it's probably a syntax or some other error *before* the line Node is pointing out.

For instance, consider the snippet below.

```js
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        res.json(await mySvc.myFunc());
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        next(err);
    }
});
```

With `node -v` reporting `v14.17.6`, this gives:

```sh
myapp $ DEBUG=myapp:* npm start

> myapp@0.0.0 start /home/me/myapp
> node ./bin/www

/home/me/myapp/routes/myroute.js:7
        res.json(await mySvc.myFunc());
                 ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

The error, of course, is on the first line of the snippet. Adding an **async** on that line, thus,

```js
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
```

fixes the issue.