# failing to run locally create-react-app. npm start gives a syntax error

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to locally run and debug my client's site but I cannot get it to start locally. I tried updating npm but with no sucess. This site was made with create react app. I am not sure if something wrong is with the code, with my npm or maybe I'm not seeing something very obvious.

I use `git clone`, then `npm i`, then `npm start` and this happens:

```
  compiler.hooks.done.tap('done', async stats => {
                                  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/filipsikora/Downloads/avrio-shop2-react-1.1/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:45:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! shop_2.0@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the shop_2.0@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I know that it highlights the word async. I tried to update npm in many ways. Maybe I screwed something up and not updated it correctly.

Here is my package.json just in case

```
{
  "name": "shop_2.0",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "firebase": "^6.6.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "raven-js": "^3.27.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-app-rewire-disable-chunks": "0.0.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^1.1.0",
    "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^0.7.8",
    "react-localization": "^1.0.15",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-scrollbar": "^0.5.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "watch": "node scripts/build-watch.js",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5"
  },
  "homepage": "/plugin/shop-app"
}
```

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you on?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica v6.11.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, When using async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306997/syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list-when-using-async)

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: That's too old. Update.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica that actually removed big part of problem. However now I have new error, and the last lines are the same as before ```Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! shop_2.0@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1```